# JavaMailSender - set dynamic value into mail template

Tags: java, spring, email

I have an entity in database `MailTemplate`, which has a mail template for some action. Now, I need to set a value into this template. Template is a simple JSP page with few fields which I want to fill at runtime. 
For Example, template is:
"Hello user ${username}!" and now I want to set username value before I'll send this mail to the user. Is it possible to do it in this way? Which tools I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution would be to create your email content using one of the wide supported templating libraries within *Spring*. Here down I list the basic steps to have your email content dynamically filled with a template using my favourite library, *[Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)*:

- Make sure the *Velocity* library jars are within your classpath.
- Create your template file, which will be a usual *HTML* file under some package, e.g. *some/package/templates/hello.html*

  ```
  <html>
    <body>
      <div>Hello user ${username}!</div>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- Use the `VelocityEngine` processing engine and `VelocityEngineUtils` utility class to populate your template with your model object and create the needed final mail text (cannot provide a whole sample since I don't know how your configuration looks like, but I provide the snippets that would be changed in most cases):

  ```
  @Autowired
  JavaMailSenderImpl sender;
  // ...

  MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
  MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
  helper.setTo("someone@host1.com");
  message.setFrom("me@host2.com");
  Map model = new HashMap();
  model.put("username", "Foo");
  String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "some/package/templates/hello.html", model);
  message.setText(text, true);

  //...
  sender.send(message);
  ```
- Last step would be to make sure that the `org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean` bean definition is declared in your application context file (Note that I didn't intorduce the missing mail beans which you should write yourself, and it is nothing but a matter of taste but the same beans can be injected using Java configuration instead of XML one):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

      <!-- Missing Java Mail Beans -->

      <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
          <property name="velocityProperties">
              <value>
                  resource.loader=class
                  class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
              </value>
          </property>
      </bean>

  </beans>
  ```

### EDIT: How to parse a dynamically constructed template content

In case the template content comes from a different source and not from a template file, step 3 is almost the one that should differ since you will have to manually provide the context to use in rendering input and evaluate the template content using one of the `org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity#evaluate` methods:

```
    import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
    //...

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSenderImpl sender;
    // ...

    String mailBody = "Hello user ${username}!"; // This will depend on how you would get your mail content
    MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);
    helper.setTo("someone@host1.com");
    message.setFrom("me@host2.com");
    // Create the context for data input
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("username", "Foo");
    // Create the Writer you would use as the output
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    // Evaluate your text entry
    Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "EvalError", mailBody);
    message.setText(writer.toString(), true);

    //...
    sender.send(message);
```

More details in [the official *Spring documenation*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html)

Comment: Thanks for help. I have a question - what if my templates are in database, not in separate package? How I can connect it with "template location" from method mergeTEmplateIntoString()?

Comment: And how can I do it using spring boot and annotations instead of xml files.

Comment: I'v updated the answer to match dynamic content parsing case, but it would be difficult to tackle the configuration issue. Meanwhile the thread should remain focused on a single issue thus you can open another one to report all problems non related to email templating... Just ping me and I would be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you again. I have created a Velocity Configuration for my Spring boot, so I hope, I've solved this problem, but if not, I'll create new topic and ask for your help. In your updated example, if I have a template as a JSP page, saved in database, could I still use it in a "mailBody"? What with DataSourceResourceLoader? My goal is to use mail template which always be a JSP page get from database.

Comment: Am I correct, that I should create string with JSP content and set correct MIME to do this?

Comment: Your text can contain any content as long as it holds data placeholders compliant with velocity syntax, they will be processed.
So where your mail body rely has no importance and should be treated as a separate concern.

Comment: Everything works as I want :). Thanks again for big help and explanation